# How to directly display the value of input

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I'm currently working on a simple page that shows the current time and date. I want to create an input where you can fill in your name, so the page says "Hi there, (your name)"

On previous project I worked with this similar function, I had to create a form and on submit I could get the value. Since this is a very simple page I want to create a simple function, is there actually a way to get the value of the input without creating a form?

See image: Jason is filled in, the input goes away and it says "Hi there, Jason"
[image]

Comment: Is there a way? Yes, first step is to Google for *"Javascript - How to get the value of an input"*

Comment: please edit your question and add some code of your attempt on achieving your goal for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

That's simple javascript, just select the input and then get its value

```
var input = document.getElementById('idFromInput');
alert(input.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you've got a paragraph tag `<p id="para">text to replace</p>`, and you want to replace the contents of that tag with the contents of a textbox `<input type="text" id="textbox" />`. You would just write a JS function like the one below, which could be triggered by something like hitting the enter key or a button.

You can expand this to do stuff like putting the textbox in a div and replacing the entire div with the contents of the textbox if you'd like the input field to disappear.

```js
function replacePara() {
  let replacementText = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = replacementText;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox" />
<p id="para">text to replace</p>
<button onclick="replacePara()">press me</button>
```